# code to apply 1D array values to .NumberFormat of 2D array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of formats in a column (n rows long) that I want to apply to a table (13 cols x n rows).  The formats stored in the column are dynamic and based upon the type of data eg currency, %, etc.  For example:  `#,##0;[Red](#,##0);"-"` or `0.0%;[Red]0.0%;"-"`

I want each row of the table to be formatted any time the column is updated. 
 Note:  I am not interested in conditional formatting.

I originally tried referring directly to `rng2` as in `row.NumberFormat = rng2` but that seemed to get stuck in a never-ending loop.

```
Sub formatrows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Set rng1 = Range("Ac7:ao400")
    Set rng2 = Range("d7:d400")
    i = 0
    Range("AC7").Select
    'rng1.ClearFormats
    For Each row In rng1.Rows
        row.NumberFormat = ActiveCell.Offset(i, -25)
        i = i + 1
    Next row
End Sub
```

Here's what I came up with seems to work but rather clunky and I'm sure there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying a bit:

```
Sub formatrows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim row As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("Ac7:ao400")
    'rng1.ClearFormats
    For Each row In rng1.Rows
        row.NumberFormat = row.EntireRow.Cells(4).value 'take format from ColD
    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Love it!  Thanks.  So a single value in the 'Cells' property refers to a column reference?  I though the order was row, then column...  lesson learned!  I appreciate that you got rid of my I counter as well.  Much better!!

Comment: A call to `Cells()` with a single number will refer to the "n'th" cell in the range on which `Cells()` is called: for a full row it will be in the n'th column of the sheet, or on a full column it would be on the n'th row.   If you call Cells() on the whole worksheet then it counts across and down, so `? ActiveSheet.Cells(columns.Count+1).Address` gives "$A$2"